# Draw from a bag of colored marbles; for each draw remove all marbles of that color

Tags: r, list, vector, dplyr, sample

I want to draw from a bag of colored marbles without replacement following some simple rules. There are multiple marbles of the same color (e.g., 5 blue, 3 red, 7 yellow, 4 green). Let say I draw 3 marbles, one marble at a time. After each draw, I remove all marbles of that color. E.g., I pick a green, I remove all green marbles from the bag; I pick a red, I remove all red marbles from the bag, etc.

I'm not totally clear on how to most efficiently remove all the marbles of the same color as the focal draw, without tons of for-loops. The below dummy code only draws marbles according a vector of draws.

```
#Dummy code
set.seed(123)
multiple_draws <- c(3,2,4,1)
bag <- c(rep("blue",5),rep("red",3),rep("yellow",7),rep("green",4))

sapply(seq(length(multiple_draws)), function(i) sample(bag, multiple_draws[i],replace=F), simplify=F)
```

Any pointer would be much appreciated.

Comment: @www sorry, fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data

```
set.seed(123)
multiple_draws <- c(3,2,4,1)
bag <- c(rep("blue",5),rep("red",3),rep("yellow",7),rep("green",4))
```

Convert your vector to a table of proportions using `prop.table(table(...))`

```
prop.table(table(bag))

# bag
     # blue     green       red    yellow 
# 0.2631579 0.2105263 0.1578947 0.3684211
```

You can sample the unique values in your `bag` setting the probability to the proportions

```
custom_sample <- function(vec, T) {
    sample(names(prop.table(table(vec))), T, replace=FALSE, prob=prop.table(table(vec)))
}
lapply(multiple_draws, function(T) custom_sample(bag, T))
# [[1]]
# [1] "yellow" "red"    "blue"  

# [[2]]
# [1] "red"   "green"

# [[3]]
# [1] "yellow" "green"  "red"    "blue"  

# [[4]]
# [1] "blue"
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the fastest approach!

Answer (score 1):

We can design a function to complete the sampling task. After each sampling, `bag <- bag[!bag %in% s]` would remove that color completely.

```
# Dummy code
set.seed(123)
multiple_draws <- c(3, 2, 4, 1) # No draw is larger than 4
bag <- c(rep("blue",5),rep("red",3),rep("yellow",7),rep("green",4))

# A function for sampling
sample_fun <- function(draw, bag){
  ans <- numeric()
  for (i in 1:draw){
    s <- sample(bag, 1, replace = FALSE)
    bag <- bag[!bag %in% s]
    ans[i] <- s
  }
  return(ans)
}

# Apply the function through multiple_draws
lapply(multiple_draws, sample_fun, bag = bag)
# [[1]]
# [1] "red"   "green" "blue" 
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "green"  "yellow"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "blue"   "yellow" "green"  "red"   
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "yellow"
```

Answer (score 0):

I will go for something like that

```
for(draw in multiple_draws){
  if(length(bag)>draw){
  color <- unique(sample(bag, draw,replace=F))
  bag <- bag[!bag %in% color]}
}
```

You actually do what you would do: you remove all marble `color` that you draw by `bag <- bag[!bag %in% color]`.

I put an if statement because I don't know what you want to do if the number of draw is higher than the number of marble.